# Recargar HTML en base a evento de router? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un componente breadcrumb, el cual esta dentro de un header,fijo en la pagina.
Es decir, se inicia una vez,etc.
Este breadcrumb ,esta suscrito a los eventos del router, para recibir un objeto data con los label y url para armar ese breadcrumb.

Me funciona excelente cuando voy de una pagina a otra (componente a otro) pero cuando estoy en un mismo componente, pero con distintos parametros de ruta, como por ejemplo: componente1/primer-parametro y componente1/segundo-parametro.  La suscripcion sigue emitiendo valores, pero mi html del breadcrumb es como que esta vez hace el cambio.

Como necesito rutas dinamicas en ciertas partes, que saco los valores del session storage, utilizo un pipe para transformar y obtener ese item.

**HTML BreadCrumb**

```html
  <section class="breadcrumbs" >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let titulo of titulos">
       <a class="title-breadcrumb" *ngIf="!!!titulo.url">
        <p *ngIf="titulo.textBefore" class="bredCrumbTitleNone">{{titulo.textBefore}}</p>
        {{ titulo.label | uppercase | breadCrumbFormat }}
        <p *ngIf="titulo.textAfter" class="bredCrumbTitleNone">{{titulo.textAfter}}</p>
      </a>

      <a class="title-breadcrumb title-breadcrumb-hover" *ngIf="!!titulo.url" [routerLink]="titulo.url | breadCrumbFormat">
        {{ titulo.label | uppercase | breadCrumbFormat  }}<span class="mat-icon arrow-tittle" >arrow_forward_ios</span>
      </a>

    </ng-container>
  </section>
```

Como ven utilizo **2 pipes**, el personalizado mio "breadCrumbFormat" que es el que obtiene el item del storage para poner el valor dinamico. y el uppercase default.

**COMPONENT TS, Breadcrumb**

```js
export class BreadcrumbsComponent implements OnDestroy {
  public titulos: any;
  public tituloSubs: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private _location: Location,
  ) {

  this.tituloSubs = this.getArgumentosRuta().subscribe((response) => {
    console.log('DATA-ROUTER',response);
      this.titulos = response.titulos;
  });
  }

  getArgumentosRuta() {
    return this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
      filter((event: ActivationEnd) => event.snapshot.firstChild === null),
      map((event: ActivationEnd) => event.snapshot.data)
      );
  }
  
 }
```

Aca esta lo importante, en esta suscripcion, es donde escucho los eventos del router cuando cambia de pagina y demas y saco el objeto data (que es el que paso en el routing) para obtener los labels y demas.

**Atentos al console.log** ya que mas abajo mostrare, que cuando se cambia de parametro en la misma ruta sigue emitiendo valor como si fuese que se cambio a otra ruta

**Routing:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndicatorsComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedGuard],
    data: {titulos:[ {label:'[STORAGE]tipoIndicador', url:''}]},
  },
]
```

Aca se arma el objeto del breadCrumb y para cuando es dinamico utilizo la key "[STORAGE]" para saber que es tengo que sacar el valor del storage y el item es la palabra posterior a esta key. **Esto lo obtengo mediante el pipe personalizado:**

**PIPE Breadcrumb**

```js
export class BreadCrumbFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(){}

  transform(value: any) {
    if(value.includes('[STORAGE]')){
      let indice = value.indexOf('[STORAGE]'),
          primeraParte = value.substring(0,indice),
          itemStorage = value.substring(indice).replace('[STORAGE]','').trim(),

          newValue = `${primeraParte}${sessionStorage.getItem(itemStorage || '')}`

      return newValue
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

Como les digo cuando voy de una ruta a otra (osea diferentes componentes) el pipe me funciona perfectamente

**Ejemplo POSITIVO**

Voy de la ruta indicadores(IndicatorsComponent) a la ruta acciones(ActionsComponent)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona sin problemas.

Ahora bien, cuando lo hago dentro del mismo componente (IndicatorsComponent) pero con diferentes parametros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven **NO CAMBIO**. se acuerdan del **console.log** de arriba? que se ejecutaba cuando pasaba un evento del router y este le asignaba el valor y demas: bueno le adjunto la captura de cuando fui a cada ruta con su parametro y se ejecuto bien sin problemas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se bien que podria ser, probe un **timeOut**, antes de asignar el valor porque capaz se setiaba antes que el session storage, pero tampoco era esto. El **ngOnChance** del breadcrumb,no emite nada.

- Como puedo **recargar el html** cuando sale el evento del router, el que imprime el console log?
- O como puedo simular un cambio de ruta, pero sin cambiarla? osea desde el componente indicador (al cambiar de un parametro a otro) para que el breadcrumb piense que hubo un cambio de ruta y quizas ahi lo tome

**TAMBIEN NOTE:** que el **router-outlet** el cual se encarga de cambiarme mis rutas, no ejecuta ningun evento cuando cambio de parametros, y si cuando voy hacia otra ruta o componente. Como puedo forzar el evento del router-outlet cuando es el mismo componente con parametros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola como estas sunset.

ok, la solucion es la siguiente, en el constructor del componente, agrega lo siguiente:

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,

  ) { 
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    };
  }
```

y listo, con eso solucionas el llamado al mismo componente. me avisas cualquier

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias puntozap, me anduvo perfectamente. Ya lo habia solucionado de otra forma, la cual acabo de comentar como respuesta aca tambien para que la pueadas ver, pero de todas formas, Me gusto mucho mas la tuya asi que voy a quedarme con esa. 
Te queria consultar la teoria, que es lo que hace basicamente la linea de codigo: this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;

Comment: me contenta que te gustara la respuesta. Te comento. nos provee una forma de reutilizar la ruta que tenemos activa, con rutas de que componen parámetros. en esta documentación, explica las maneras de su uso: https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy . estoy en la redes sociales con el mismo apodo. si deseas que te siga ayudando. o por este medio tambien. Saludos

Comment: buenisimo !
AHora estoy con el siguiente problema:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/461599/problema-tema-personalizado-angular-material

Comment: puntozap, sabes que ahora, con esa linea de codigo.. me funciona todo bien,pero no me respeta la clase cuando un router link es active. osea tenia la clase is-active que cambiaba el color del item, pero ahora al agregar esa linea no me pone ese estilo.

Answer (score 0):

Gente lo resolvi de la siguiente forma.

En el routing donde mando los label y url para el armado del breadcrumb, le agregue una propiedad mas para cuando es una ruta con parametros:

**Routing:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndicatorsComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedGuard],
    data: {titulos:[ {label:'', url:'',isParam:true}]}

]
```

Como en el breadCrumb.ts la suscricion escucha los eventos y el snapshot, ahi puedo detectar los parametros. entonces hice lo siguiente:

```js
export class BreadcrumbsComponent implements OnDestroy {
  public titulos: any;
  public tituloSubs: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private _location: Location,
    private helpers:HelpersService
  ) {

    this.tituloSubs = this.getArgumentosRuta().subscribe((response) => {
      
      if(!!response.data.titulos){
        // chequeo si el objeto data tiene algun label/url con parametros y lo modifico
        response.data['titulos'].forEach(element => {
        if(element.isParam) element.label = this.helpers.capitalizeString(Object.values(response.params)[0])
        })

        
        this.titulos = response.data.titulos
      }
    });



  }

  getArgumentosRuta() {
    return this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
      filter((event: ActivationEnd) => event.snapshot.firstChild === null),
      map((event: ActivationEnd) => event.snapshot)
    );
  }
```

Basicamente,chequeo si el objeto data tiene algun label/url con parametros y le asigno como label en este caso,el nombre del parametro. Si no tiene parametros no entra en el if y sigue su flujo normal.